# How to assign a list with keys and values from a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a real beginner and I want to know if there's method where you can assign the keys and values from a dictionary to a list of tuples? If there's a method to do this, I also would like to know the full source code?

This is the given dictionary

```py
dict_count = {'z': 4, 'b': 4, 'a': 6}
```

I expect the output to look like this 
[(‘a’ 6), (‘b’ 4), (‘z’, 4)]

Comment: or just `my_dict.items()`

Comment: @JoranBeasley, in Python 3.x, `items()` does not return a list.

Comment: sure ... solved with your answer so np :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But please do not use `dict` as an identifier! It is a built-in function (a dictionary constructor).

```
list(d.items())
#[('z', 4), ('b', 4), ('a', 6)]
```